# Run Registry File Remotely with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-server-2008

I'm using the following script to run `test.reg` on multiple remote systems:

```
$computers = Get-Content computers.txt

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
  regedit /i /s "\\SERVER\C$\RegistryFiles\test.reg"
}
```

The script doesn't error, but the registry entry doesn't import on any of the systems.

I know `test.reg` file is a valid registry file because I copied it over, ran it manually, and the registry key imports. I also made sure PowerShell Remoting is enabled on the remote computers.

Any ideas why the registry key isn't importing?

Comment: Could be a double hop issue. Can you read the reg file inside the script block (e.g. with `Get-Content`)?

Comment: What hive is your registry file test.reg using?

Comment: @ Colyn1337 - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test

Comment: @ mike z - Not sure how to run the test you want (with Get_Content)

Comment: @user1040362 Run `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers[0] -ScriptBlock { gc "\\SERVER\C$\RegistryFiles\test.reg" }`. Do you get the content of the file back or an error?

Comment: @mikez

I get this error:

`Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Scripts\RegistryFileDeployment\Test.ps1:1 char:41
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers[ <<<< 0] -ScriptBlock { gc "C:\Downloads\RegistryFileHost\test.reg" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: @mikez  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @user1040362 With that last one? Obviously, $computers is null. But you've also changed the path to a local path instead of a remote server admin share which now means you've changed the problem. If it still is not working, I'm not sure what the problem is then.

Comment: @mikez I ran the command you posted on the server that hosts the registry file (which is also where I ran the command in the OP from), so it shouldn't matter that I changed it to the local path.  I thought you wanted to see if that command returned an error (it did) or if it returned the content of the .reg file.  Just running gc "C:\Downloads\RegistryFileHost\test.reg" does return the contents of the .reg file.  Am I missing something? Maybe you wanted me to run that command from a remote server? Doing that works as well.

Comment: @user1040362 The issue that people very commonly run into is trying to remote to another server and from there access protected resources on a third machine. That is what your OP looked like it was doing. If that is not your scenario, you can ignore my comment. Yes it matters very much if the path is local or remote. You will be able to access local resources when remoting, however you will not be able to flow credentials to be granted access to resources on other machines while in the remote session.

Comment: @mikez  Thanks...I'll be more explicit.   I'm running Script1 from Server1 which hosts test.reg. The script is supposed to run the command regedit /i /s \\SERVER1\C$\Downloads\RegistryFileHost\test.reg on all the systems in computers.txt.  But this errors.  Running gc \\SERVER1\C$\Downloads\RegistryFileHost\test.reg'on the remote systems succeeds, so I know they can read this .reg file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the best way not to mess with issues related to server authentication and cut down on complexity just to pass Reg file as parameter to function.

```
$regFile = @"
 Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"MaxUserPort"=dword:00005000
"TcpTimedWaitDelay"=dword:0000001e
"@

Invoke-Command -ComputerName computerName -ScriptBlock {param($regFile) $regFile | out-file $env:temp\a.reg; 
    reg.exe import $env:temp\a.reg } -ArgumentList $regFile
```

Comment: Nice! This is better than copying the .reg file over.

Answer (score 2):

I posted on some PowerShell forums and finally got this working.

I had to 1) move the $newfile variable inside the loop and 2) comment out the $ in the path stored in the $newfile variable.

For reference, the final script looks like this if anyone wants to use it:

```
    $servers = Get-Content servers.txt

    $HostedRegFile = "C:\Scripts\RegistryFiles\test.reg"

    foreach ($server in $servers)

    {

    $newfile = "\\$server\c`$\Downloads\RegistryFiles\test.reg"

    New-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ItemType directory -Path \\$server\C$\Downloads\RegistryFiles

    Copy-Item $HostedRegFile -Destination $newfile

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {

    Start-Process -filepath "C:\windows\regedit.exe" -argumentlist "/s C:\Downloads\RegistryFiles\test.reg"

    }

    }
```